# how to get VueJs component to combine json data and a template at runtime

Tags: json, vue.js

the template is ""
which I am trying to combine with three different JSON files, in three separate components, in a Vue-Tabs UI
Here's the repo: https://github.com/georgehowell/ColonialState_homepage-slider_v2

Here's the error I am getting for each of the components: [image]

Answer (score 0):

<Slider.vue>
needed an 'Array' prop added to the script 
`` export default {
  name: 'Slider',
  props: {
`   listing: Array
}
} ``

Each parent component (using 'Slider') needed to look like this:

```
<template>
  <Slider v-if="listing!=''" :listing="listing" />
```